# Need assistance with scrapping details from a website

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

am new to web scraping, am trying this workflow but NoSuchElementException pop's up.
go to amazon.in >> type in iphone13 >> click on the 1st listing >> scrap the details like exchange offers, replacement etc.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://www.amazon.in/')
driver.find_element_by_id('twotabsearchtextbox').send_keys('iPhone 13')
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id('nav-search-submit-text').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="a-link-normal s-underline-text s-underline-link-text s-link-style a-text-normal"]').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("a-section a-spacing-none sopp-offer-container")
```

Answer (score 0):

The step

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="a-link-normal s-underline-text s-underline-link-text s-link-style a-text-normal"]').click()`

Opens a new window for the `selected prdouct`

You will need to switch to the new window opened using

Your solution would look like

```
driver.get('https://www.amazon.in/')
driver.find_element_by_id('twotabsearchtextbox').send_keys('iPhone 13')
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id('nav-search-submit-text').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="a-link-normal s-underline-text s-underline-link-text s-link-style a-text-normal"]').click()
time.sleep(2)
handles = driver.window_handles
size = len(handles)
parent_handle = driver.current_window_handle
for x in range(size):
  if handles[x] != parent_handle:  
  driver.switch_to.window(handles[x])
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='a-section a-spacing-none sopp-offer-container']")
```

Comment: Hi @mentalist can you try the above solution